# How show chinese characters in a jTexArea

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextarea, chinese-locale

I have a JTexArea in a frame and i want to show chinese characters. My application shows perfectly other languajes like russian, spanish,... but I have problems with chinese.
Jlabels, Jbuttons and other components works perfectly in chinese but in my texArea I get only squares

My JTextArea:

```
textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setAutoscrolls(false);
textArea.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", textArea.getFont().getStyle(), 11)); 
scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
```

I append text:

```
Application.textArea.append(Messages.getString("myKey1") +"\n");
```

Any Idea? Thanks.

Comment: `textArea.setDefaultLocale(java.util.Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);`

Comment: Recommended reading: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html